# MySQL - modifying a query (NOT NULL)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write commands to retrieve parts of my database that are already set up

I need to produce a list of `teacher_id`'s with a count of the number of lessons each teacher has in a day.

I am using

```
SELECT teacher_id, COUNT(lesson_time)
FROM lessons
WHERE lesson_time > 0
GROUP BY teacher_id;
```

This statement retrieve's all teacher Id's and displays how many lessons each of them have, however, I wanted the statement to include the teachers that have 0 lessons as well.

`lesson_time` is set to `NOT NULL`, so I presume that 0 must be written in the cells where the teacher has 0 lessons.

The teacher_id is in the table "Teachers"

Comment: Just remove the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: the where condition doesn't seem to have any effect on what is retrieved

Comment: i have just realized that you should have teachers table to join so please post teachers table schema too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SELF JOIN

```
SELECT
  p.people_id,
  p.first_name,
  IFNULL(COUNT(l.lesson_time),0) AS LessonCount
FROM people AS p
  LEFT JOIN lessons AS l
    ON t.people_id = l.teacher_id
GROUP by p.people_id
```

This is modified query that will fetch all the teachers from teachers table and than it will join lessons table for count. And if any count is not available it will dispaly 0.

Comment: of course if teachers table is available this query will be modified for what exactly OP wants

Comment: @MattRhodes when ever you question on SO please provide 4 things. Complete schema(which you haven't provided you should have provided people schema) , sample data , desired output and what you have tried. Please provide people schema so i can modify this